# Android Studio on Mac Yosemite 10.10.1, emulater_x86 show black screen

Tags: android, macos

I am new to Mac, I installed Android Studio on MacBook Pro running on Yosemite 10.10.1.

I was unable to run emulator_x86 or emulator64_x86, it just show black screen and freezed. Haxm-macosx_r05.zip (1.1.1)  was installed.

On the Run tab, the following message:-

> /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_6_API_21
>   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Just give a try to the `ARM` emulator

Comment: Yes, ARM emulator is working.